# How to call a non-jquery object method inside an angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, polymer

I'm using Polymer and AngularJS together, and I want the page to show a toast after a successful form submitting.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-view></div>
<paper-toast id="toast" text="{{$rootScope.message}}" show-toast></paper-toast>
```

My `$routeProvider` has indicated different templates and controllers for different routes, so I put the toast element outside. Since the submitting causes a page jump, I need to put the message where the toast element can access, i.e. `$rootScope`.

And JS:

```
app.directive('showToast', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        var toast = document.querySelector('#toast');
        if ($rootScope.message != '') {
            toast.show();
            toast.addEventListener('core-overlay-close-completed', function() {
                $rootScope.message = '';
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

But an error occurs saying that `undefined is not a function at link`, pointing to `toast.show()`. But if I put the content of `link` function into that page controller, it can work.

What's wrong with `directive`? And as you can see, the `link` function has a parameter `element`, but since the `show()` method is not a jQuery method, I don't know how to call it through `element`.

Comment: there's an angular module/directive for `toaster` , would make it easier to just use that. Can inject it as service in any controller or other directive

Comment: In this case `element` injected into the link function should also be the element with id `toast`.

Comment: @DavinTryon but it's a jquery object. How can I convert it? The `get()` method is not available in jqLite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies. I made a mistake. the `element` parameter is an array of DOM nodes, so I can just call `show()` method by `element[0].show()`. Sorry for confusing if any.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
var toast = document.querySelector('#toast');
```

Because the toast element should be a global variable on the window object (you could access it by using `window.toast` if there is some other scope variable interfering with it)

Comment: But `document.querySelector('#toast')` and `window.toast` return the same thing, the `paper-toast` DOM element. When I use it in a controller, I can call `show()` method on this element, but error occurs in `directive`.